# Angular guard api call automatically canceled

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using a guard to check if a user has sufficient authorizations to access a page in my angular app. It makes an asynchronous call to an api in order to get that information. It works fine most of the time.
I'm running some performance tests with Chrome in order to optimize the app behaviour on mobile devices, and while testing in Slow 3G throttling, the call made by the guard seems to be automatically canceled after around 445ms

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

**auth.service**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Authorization } from '@models';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getAuthorizations(id: number): Observable<Authorizations> {
        return this.http
            .get(`/api/authorizations`)
            .pipe(
                map(res => {
                    return !!res && (<any>res).data.authorizedActions
                        ? (<any>res).data.authorizedActions
                        : null;
                })
            );
    }
}
```

**app.module**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomeComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'budget',
                canActivate: [BudgetGuard],
                loadChildren: () => import('./budget').then(m => m.BudgetModule),
            },
];
```

**budget.guard**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthorizedBusinessAction } from '@tproj/models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class BudgetGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        const userId = route.params.userId;
        return this.authService
            .getAuthorizations(userId)
            .pipe(map(auth => {
                if (auth.userIsAuthorized) {
                   return auth.userIsAuthorized;
                }
                this.router.navigate([`/`]);
            }));
    }
}
```

Any clue is welcomed, thanks

Comment: `BudgetGuard` = `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` ?

Comment: I don't know what the problem actually is, but I'd advise  you to use `canLoad` instead of `canActivate` when you're dealing with lazy-loaded modules. If using `canActivate` on a module, even though it returns false, the module would've already been loaded. This won't happen if you use `canLoad`.

Comment: That would definitely make more sense, thanks for the help !

Comment: The canLoad method doesn't pass an ActivatedRouteSnapshot parameter though, how can I get the needed params like with canActivate ? (I tried with the snapshot of ActivatedRoute but it doesn't store the same params)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you not making the api call inside the guard, but instead make the API call once root app loaded, and save the user Object inside an observable, and inside BudgetGuard, you may subscribe to it.

BudgetGuard:

```
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
        this._authService.currentUser.subscribe(u => {
            this.authorized = u != undefined ? true : false
        })
    }
    canActivate() {return this.authorized}
```

Inside the auth.service you may do something similar to:

getUser() { this.currentUser.next(user)}

You may take a look at angular interceptors as well.